# Abort crashes “/apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so”

Tags: android

Google Play Console is showing **abort** crashes, the stack trace is the following:

```
backtrace:
  #00  pc 000000000004f064  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (abort+164)
  #00  pc 000000000004b10c  /system/lib64/libc++.so (abort_message+248)
  #00  pc 000000000004b2d0  /system/lib64/libc++.so (demangling_terminate_handler()+212)
  #00  pc 000000000004bdc4  /system/lib64/libc++.so (std::__terminate(void (*)())+12)
  #00  pc 000000000004b4e0  /system/lib64/libc++.so (__cxxabiv1::failed_throw(__cxxabiv1::__cxa_exception*)+28)
  #00  pc 000000000004b448  /system/lib64/libc++.so (__cxa_throw+112)
  #00  pc 000000000004ef9c  /system/lib64/libc++.so (operator new(unsigned long)+96)
  #00  pc 000000000009a53c  /system/lib64/libc++.so (std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::__grow_by_and_replace(unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, char const*)+156)
  #00  pc 000000000009a440  /system/lib64/libc++.so (std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >::append(char const*, unsigned long)+100)
  #00  pc 00000000000104f0  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::ReadFdToString(android::base::borrowed_fd, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*)+192)
  #00  pc 00000000000105f0  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::ReadFileToString(std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> > const&, std::__1::basic_string<char, std::__1::char_traits<char>, std::__1::allocator<char> >*, bool)+192)
  #00  pc 0000000000048e78  /system/lib64/libunwindstack.so (unwindstack::Maps::Parse()+116)
  #00  pc 000000000000dc7c  /system/lib64/libbacktrace.so (UnwindStackMap::Build()+532)
  #00  pc 000000000000e11c  /system/lib64/libbacktrace.so (BacktraceMap::Create(int, bool)+128)
  #00  pc 000000000059da74  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadList::Dump(std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, bool)+244)
  #00  pc 000000000053aebc  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::Runtime::Abort(char const*)+1896)
  #00  pc 000000000001394c  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::SetAborter(std::__1::function<void (char const*)>&&)::$_3::__invoke(char const*)+76)
  #00  pc 00000000000130cc  /system/lib64/libbase.so (android::base::LogMessage::~LogMessage()+312)
  #00  pc 000000000033e400  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (void art::CheckedCall<int (void*, unsigned long, int), unsigned char*, unsigned long, int>(int  const(&)(void*, unsigned long, int), char const*, unsigned char*, unsigned long, int)+212)
  #00  pc 0000000000338f30  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::jit::JitCodeCache::Reserve(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitMemoryRegion*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, art::ArtMethod*, art::ArrayRef<unsigned char const>*, art::ArrayRef<unsigned char const>*)+704)
  #00  pc 00000000001d7434  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::OptimizingCompiler::JitCompile(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitCodeCache*, art::jit::JitMemoryRegion*, art::ArtMethod*, bool, bool, art::jit::JitLogger*)+1696)
  #00  pc 0000000000110cf0  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart-compiler.so (art::jit::JitCompiler::CompileMethod(art::Thread*, art::jit::JitMemoryRegion*, art::ArtMethod*, bool, bool)+232)
  #00  pc 0000000000326e7c  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::jit::Jit::CompileMethod(art::ArtMethod*, art::Thread*, bool, bool, bool)+1104)
  #00  pc 000000000032f3b8  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::jit::JitCompileTask::Run(art::Thread*)+668)
  #00  pc 00000000005a6694  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Run()+108)
  #00  pc 00000000005a6164  /apex/com.android.art/lib64/libart.so (art::ThreadPoolWorker::Callback(void*)+192)
  #00  pc 00000000000b6374  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__pthread_start(void*)+64)
  #00  pc 0000000000050fa4  /apex/com.android.runtime/lib64/bionic/libc.so (__start_thread+64)
```

I couldn't reproduce this bug and didn't find information either.

This bug happens most of the time in Android 11

Anyone has an idea what thing fire this bug?.

Any information is appreciated.
Thank you.